# how to save contact us form in database of magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, contact-us

i need to save contact us form fields in magento database please help.

Thanks in advance.

following is the form.phtml file. file path is ,

app\design\frontend\mypackage\mytheme\template\contacts\form.phtml

```
<div id="messages_product_view"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?></div>

<div class="row box-1-contact" id="inquiryForm">
<div class="col-md-12 page-title title-c">
    <h1><?php echo $this->__('Contact Us');?></h1>
</div>
<?php if($this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('google-map')->toHtml()) { ?>
<div class="contact-map-wrap col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('google-map')->toHtml() ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<form class="contact-form col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl(); ?>contacts/index/post/" id="contactForm" method="post">
    <div class="form-wrapper">
        <ul class="form-list">
            <li class="fields">
                <div class="field">
                    <div class="input-box">
                    <div class="input-group">
 <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><i class="icon-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</span>
     <input name="name" id="name" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Your name') ?>" onfocus="if(this.value=='<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Your name...') ?>') this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Your name...') ?>';" value="<?php echo ($this->helper('contacts')->getUserName())?$this->htmlEscape($this->helper('contacts')->getUserName()):Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Your name...'); ?>" class="form-control required-entry" type="text" />
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div></br>
                <div class="field">
                    <div class="input-box">
                    <div class="input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><i class="icon-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</span>
                        <input name="email" id="email1" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Your email') ?>" onfocus="if(this.value=='<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Your email...') ?>') this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Your email...') ?>';" value="<?php echo ($this->helper('contacts')->getUserEmail())?$this->htmlEscape($this->helper('contacts')->getUserEmail()):Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Your email...'); ?>" class="form-control required-entry validate-email" type="text" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div></br>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="input-box field">
                <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><i class="icon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </span>
                    <input name="subject" id="subject" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Title') ?>" onfocus="if(this.value=='<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Subject') ?>') this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Subject') ?>';" value="<?php echo ($this->helper('contacts')->getUserEmail())?$this->htmlEscape($this->helper('contacts')->getUserEmail()):Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Subject'); ?>" class="form-control" type="text" />  
                </div>
                </div></br>
            </li>
            <li class="wide">
                <div class="input-box">
                <div class="input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><i class="icon-comments" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</span>
                    <textarea name="comment" id="comment" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Comment') ?>" onfocus="if(this.value=='<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Comment...') ?>') this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Comment...') ?>';" value="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Comment...'); ?>" class="required-entry form-control" cols="10" rows="7"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Comment...') ?></textarea>
                </div>
                </div></br>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons-set">
        <input type="text" name="hideit" id="hideit" value="" style="display:none !important;" />
        <button type="submit" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Send Email') ?>" class="button"><span <span><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Send Email') ?></span></span> </button>
    </div>
</form>
<div style="clear:both; padding:15px 0px;">&nbsp;</div>

    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('info-store')->toHtml() ?>

</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var contactForm = new VarienForm('contactForm', false);
function doAjax() {
    var formId = 'inquiryForm';
    var myForm = new VarienForm(formId, true);
    var postUrl = '<?php echo $this->getUrl("contactus/index/updateinfo") ?>';
    var email = $('inquiryEmail').getValue();
    var number = $('inquiryNumber').getValue();
    var comment = '<?php echo 'Inquiry request for '. $_product->getName() .' ['. $_product->getId() .']'; ?>';
   // if (myForm.validator.validate()) {
        new Ajax.Updater(
            { success:'formSuccess' }, postUrl, {
                method:'post',
                asynchronous:true,
                evalScripts:false,
                onComplete:function(request, json) {
                    var data = request.responseText.evalJSON();                     
                    if (false == data.error) {              
                        $(formId).hide();   
                        $('formSuccess').show();                            
                        $("formSuccess").update("Your request has been submitted succesfully.");                            
                    } else {
                        $("formSuccess").update("Some thing is wrong, Please try later");
                    }
                },
                onLoading:function(request, json){
                    Element.show('formLoader');
                },
                parameters: {email:email, number : number, comment : comment},
            }
        );
   // }
}  
new Event.observe('inquiryBtn', 'click', function(e){
    e.stop();
    doAjax();
}); 
//]]>
</script>
```

and core controller of this form is ,

app\code\core\Mage\Contacts\controllers\IndexController.php

```
class Mage_Contacts_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
const XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT  = 'contacts/email/recipient_email';
const XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER     = 'contacts/email/sender_email_identity';
const XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE   = 'contacts/email/email_template';
const XML_PATH_ENABLED          = 'contacts/contacts/enabled';

public function preDispatch()
{
    parent::preDispatch();

    if( !Mage::getStoreConfigFlag(self::XML_PATH_ENABLED) ) {
        $this->norouteAction();
    }
}

public function indexAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('contactForm')
        ->setFormAction( Mage::getUrl('*/*/post', array('_secure' => $this->getRequest()->isSecure())) );

    $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
    $this->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');
    $this->renderLayout();
}

public function postAction()
{
    $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    if ( $post ) {
        $translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
        /* @var $translate Mage_Core_Model_Translate */
        $translate->setTranslateInline(false);
        try {
            $postObject = new Varien_Object();
            $postObject->setData($post);

            $error = false;

            if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['name']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }

            if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['comment']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }

            if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['email']), 'EmailAddress')) {
                $error = true;
            }

            if (Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['hideit']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }

            if ($error) {
                throw new Exception();
            }
            $mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
            /* @var $mailTemplate Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template */
            $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
                ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
                ->sendTransactional(
                    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
                    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),
                    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT),
                    null,
                    array('data' => $postObject)
                );

            if (!$mailTemplate->getSentSuccess()) {
                throw new Exception();
            }

            $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us.'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');

            return;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        }

    } else {
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }
}

}
```

I want to save this fields in custom table in magento database please help.

Comment: Hi Kiyara, Welcome to Magento Stack Exchange. Please provide valid codes or be specific in your question. Your question seems to be too broad.

Comment: please see updated question

Comment: if you have any idea please share

Answer (score 1):

you need to create controller file and custom table at database to save contact us data.

review this [link](http://www.letsknowit.com/save-contact-us-queries-in-database-magento) for more detail.

THanks

Comment: i tried this but not working

Comment: <?php
    require_once 'Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php';
    class Letsknowit_Contactus_IndexController extends  Mage_Contacts_IndexController
    {
    
 
    public function postAction()
    {
       $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
       
 
       /* code to save query , you can write our insert query here*/
       if ( $post ) {
          
                               $model = Mage::getModel('contactus/contactus'); 
    $model->setData($post);
    $model->save();
 
            }
     
 
        }
       ?>

Comment: i think something goes wrong in this controller please provode me mysql  query to save data

Comment: this is my insert query

Comment: $write = Mage::getSingleton("core/resource")->getConnection("core_write");

// Concatenated with . for readability
$query = "insert into mage_example "
       . "(name, email, subject, comment) values "
       . "(:name, :email, :subject, :comment)";

$binds = array(
    'name'    => "name' or 1=1",
    'email'   => "email",
    'subject' => "subject",
    'comment'    => "comment",
);
$write->query($query, $binds);

Comment: are you sure this controller is correct